# How to convert base64 content to file object in client side and send it to controller

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to send a list of files to the backend:

```js
var formdata = new FormData();
if(fileObjectList.length>0){
  Object.keys(fileObjectList).forEach(i => {
    formdata.append('file' + i, fileObjectList[i]);
  });
}
formdata.append('requestModel', JSON.stringify(request));
req.open("POST", 'contorller');
req.send(formdata);
```

The controller converts the file to base64 data.

To send the data via email, we have to attach the content as base64,
which I again send to the controller as a file object.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please read [ask] and provide the context, and/or post code samples of a [mcve] of what you have done, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jszip to add files in a zip and send whole doc as base64 in single request. check the below link for more information [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

```js
                var jszip = new ZipHandler;
                var formdata = new FormData();
                if(fileObjectList.length>0){
                Object.keys(fileObjectList).forEach(i => {
                      jszip.addFile(`${fileObjectList[i]}.fileTypeExt`, '(buffer|base64)');
                    });
                };
                var zipcomplete = await t.generate({
                          base64: !0,
                          compression: "DEFLATE"
                     });
                formdata.append('fileDataZip', zipcomplete);
                formdata.append('requestModel', JSON.stringify(request));
                req.open("POST", 'contorller');
                req.send(formdata)
```

by using C# use below code to save base64 file

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("/fileDataZip.zip", Convert.FromBase64String(fileDataZip));
```

By using nodejs utilize the below code to save base64 file

```
require("fs").writeFile("fileDataZip.zip", fileDataZip, 'base64');
```